# What are the Differences between Analog and Digital Devices?

Tags: digital-logic, analog

Consider a '555 Timer IC', Is it a Analog or Digital Device ?
Or consider a more complex IC as a Microprocessor. 
I know the difference between a analog and Digital signal. But what is the difference between Analog and Digital Devices ?

Comment: Digital is perverted analog.

Comment: Primarily, a digital device is like an analog one, except that the transistors are intended to be driven fully on or fully off, not somewhere in between.

Comment: In edge cases like the 555 it depends which marketing team is tasked with selling it.

Comment: @MattYoung , to be precise, digital is analog with a bipolar disorder. Mixed signals components suffer from an identity crisis.

Comment: Reminded of this not-too-closely-related tangent: someone once got funding for iterative feeding of analog signals through logic chips, with [mildy interesting results](http://discovermagazine.com/1998/jun/evolvingaconscio1453) (much less interesting than that fluffy hype piece seems to be trying to assert, frankly).

Answer (score 11):

**Everything** is analog / analogue !

**Digital** is a simplification of analog, instead of that a voltage can have **any** value between 0 and 5 V, for example 1.23456789 V (Analog) we only consider 2 states: 0 V and call it "0" and 5 V and call that "1".

That is regarding signals and you already knew this.

You can do something similar with circuits and devices. In essence, **all circuits and devices are Analog**, yes even that CPU in your PC. The voltages inside it are not "0" or "1" they're 0.002338 V or 1.23328 V.
But to make things easier we make an abstraction and say it's either zero or one.

However the **core functionality** of that **CPU** or any other **digital device** can be described fully when considering only the zeros and the ones. So in my opinion, if you can fully describe the functionality of a device with only ones and zeros, it must be digital !

Coming back to the 555 timer. Note that part of its functionality is to charge a capacitor, that voltage can have **any** value between a lower and an upper threshold. I call that analog behaviour. Inside the 555 there is a flip-flop which has two states, you could call that digital.

So the 555 is more of a mixture, mostly analog but with a bit of digital.

Most CPUs and MicroControllers are considered **digital** although some CPUs have voltage regulators and/or a PLL (with an Analog oscillator) inside and/or an ADC which is very Analog indeed. And yet, no-one calls CPUs and MicroControllers analog devices (but secretly they are !)

Comment: Indeed everything is analogue +1

Comment: The 555 is indeed a "mixed signal" device. You can think of voltage comparators as a way of interfacing analog to digital, and indeed, the 555 has two of them (pins 2 and 6). Similarly, an open-collector "switch" (pin 7) is one way of interfacing digital to analog. Pin 5 is also an analog pin, but pins 3 (output) and 4 (input) are strictly digital.

Comment: FET devices printed in real chips do vary b/w analog and digital.  Analog devices will generally be much larger with tighter tolerances; digital will be as small as possible.

Comment: @jbord39 *digital will be as small as possible* In digital also many transistor widths are used, for example for powerfull (high fanout) output buffers/drivers. Analog designs also need to be made as small as possible for cost reasons. I design analog circuits using FETs, these FETs are designed to make digital circuits. They happen to work for Analog also ;-)

Comment: Yes, they work for analog but it is not typically done that way.  Using the smallest FET (1 finger, 2 fins) for analog applications would be ridiculous as the process variations at this small of a size are huge.  Instead analog FET's are typically layed out in a multi-fingered fashion, distributed over a larger area.  The idea here is that any local variation will cancel out to create a more robust FET.  FET's for critical analog applications that I have encountered were typically at least 100x larger than the digital FET's minimum size.

Comment: @jbord39 *as the process variations at this small of a size are huge* No, they're the same as for large transistors. What you mean is that **matching** of 2 identical transistors is **much worse**. But I don't need good matching for **every** transistor. Only where I need it I use large transistors. The matching of transistors can be simulated using Monte Carlo analysis so I can quite easily determine if my transistors are large enough or can be made smaller. Number of fins is also irrelevant for matching, it is the **gate area** that matters.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: I am not talking about FET matching.  I am talking about the potential variation for each FET printed, which determines basic characteristics like delay or gain.  I find it hard to believe that as an analog designer you are unfamiliar with basic process technology.  If you take 10 FET's of 1 finger, 1 fin and average the values, it will be closer to expected than a single 1 finger, 1 fin FET 99.999% of the time.